# React/React-Router - TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm a React novice, trying my hand at creating my first application. I've been trying to keep it super simple so far whilst following some tutorials and documentation.

The below code is causing a TypeError as shown in the image here
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Roqh1.png)

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'


const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/hospitals">Find a Patient</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/hospitals" component={Hospitals}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

const HOSPITALS = [
  { id: 0, name: 'St James', patients: [
     { id: 1, location: 'Maple ward' },
     { id: 2, location: 'Birch ward' },
     { id: 3, location: 'Pine ward' }
  ]},
  { id: 1, name: 'Harrogate Hospital', patients: [
    { id: 4, location: 'Sycamore ward' },
    { id: 5, location: 'Fern ward' },
    { id: 6, location: 'Oak ward' }
  ]},
  { id: 2, name: 'Leeds General Infirmary', patients: [
    { id: 7, location: 'Trout ward' },
    { id: 8, location: 'Eel ward' },
    { id: 9, location: 'Salmon ward' }
  ]}
]

const find = (id) => HOSPITALS.find(p => p.id === id)


const Hospitals = ( {match} ) => {
  let hospitals = HOSPITALS.map((hospital) => {
    return (
      <li key={hospital.id}>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/${hospital.id}/patients`} >
          {hospital.name}
        </Link>
      </li>
    )
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hospitals</h2>
      <ul>
        {hospitals}
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route path={`${match.url}/:hospitalID/patients`} component={Patients}/>
    </div>
  )
}

const Patients = ( {match} ) => {
  const hospitalArray = find(match.params.hospitalID)

  let patients = hospitalArray.patients.map((patient) => {
    return (
      <li key={patient.id}>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/${patient.id}`} >
          {patient.location}
        </Link>
      </li>
    )
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Patient for {match.params.hospitalID}</h2>
      <ul>
        {patients}
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route path={`${match.url}/:patientID`} component={PatientDetail}/>

    </div>
  )
}


const PatientDetail = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Patient details for {match.params.patientID}</h2>
  </div>
)




export default App;
```

Any help or insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: hospitalArray is not defined which suggests your find method is not working.

Comment: Can you `console.log` your `match.params` in your Patients component? It looks like `hospitalID` might not be defined there, so your `find` method fails

Comment: `console.log(match.params.hospitalID)` logs the correct response

Comment: @Antifish @BravoZulu I think i've found the issue. I needed to change `const find = (id) => HOSPITALS.find(p => p.id === id)` to `const find = (id) => HOSPITALS.find(p => p.id == id)` (notice the '==' instead of '===). Not sure why this makes a difference

Comment: probably because when you read it from the `params` the `hospitalID` is a string, for example `'1'`. So when you `===` with the number `1`, you get false, but instead with `==` it's true. That's Javascript haha